# Not showing Yes/Maybe/No buttons in ICAL-event to emails

Tags: javascript, node.js, icalendar

I'm unable to get the Yes/Maybe/No buttons in mails while using ICAL event . Here is my content used to call an ICAL event

Image as shown below with output:
[enter image description here][1] But I need with Yes/Maybe/NO buttons in mails. and also I'm unable to send invite mails to organizer and attendees mentioned in content.
Please help me out to sort this issue.
Thank you

Comment: Please add image and configuration/code to provide further clarification of your problem/issue

Answer (score 1):

in order to get the buttons yes/no/maybe you need to send the ics with method REQUEST

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//sebbo.net//ical-generator//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:52c2ab56-7488-41bb-8233-9925baffd159
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20220524T104935Z
DTSTART:20220524T104935Z
DTEND:20220524T114935Z
SUMMARY:This is an example
LOCATION:Corleone
DESCRIPTION:will it work 
ORGANIZER;CN="Jorge":mailto:test@test.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE;CN="Ariel Litvin":MAILTO:blabla@bla.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```